# Predictions using Convolutional Neural Networks and DL4J

Tags: neural-network, dl4j

This is my first time working with DL4J (Deep Learning for Java) and also my first Convolutional Neural Network. My Goal is to use the Convolutional Neural Netowrk to give me some predicted values about an image. I gathered and labelled my images myself. The labels or expected outputs consist of two numbers between 0 and 1 (I just wrote them in the file name like 0.01x0.87.jpg).
Now I can't find any way to use the DataSetIterator Class which DL4J uses so that I can also set my label values.

Is there a simple way to tell DL4J that I want to train my Network to recognize that image 0.01x0.01.jpg should spit out the values 0.01 and 0.01?

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do is usually known as regression. In contrast to classification where you want to either have a 0 or 1 output, in regression any value can be the target.

In your case, you will likely want to use a network architecture that uses either a sigmoid  (which forces your values to be between 0 and 1) or an identity (which keeps the values as is, i.e. allows for them to be outside of the 0 to 1 range) activation function.

As you have two values that you are trying to predict, you will have to also define that you are using two outputs.

So much for your model architecture.

For data loading, you can use the [ImageRecordReader](https://deeplearning4j.org/api/latest/org/datavec/image/recordreader/ImageRecordReader.html), but also pass it a [PathMultiLabelGenerator](https://deeplearning4j.org/api/latest/org/datavec/api/io/labels/PathMultiLabelGenerator.html) of your own. When you implement the PathMultiLabelGenerator interface, you will get the full path of the image as a string, and you can do whatever you want with it, like for example remove the file ending, split on `x` and parse your filename into a list of [DoubleWritable](https://deeplearning4j.org/api/latest/org/datavec/api/writable/DoubleWritable.html). `DoubleWritable` is just a simple wrapper class for `double` so creating that is as easy as just instantiating it by passing the actual value to the constructor.

To create a dataset iterator you can now follow the documentation on [RecordReaderDataSetIterator](https://deeplearning4j.org/api/latest/org/deeplearning4j/datasets/datavec/RecordReaderDataSetIterator.html).